# Is there any site on the SE network to ask about song-related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask some questions about songs.

1. What is the meaning of that song?
2. What is the reason for that song is written?
3. What song cultures are out there?
4. what about the history of songs cultures, bands.

I have similar questions for some songs. I have found some sites to get information about those questions but not in Stack Exchange sites. Is there any here?

Comment: yeap.I have looked at it. http://music.stackexchange.com/is about practicing music. not to ask above like questions.isn't it?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Try not to be abrasive :/ It's not apparent if he looked at the list or not (since there is no site matching the criteria), so just [assume good faith](http://enwp.org/WP:AGF).

Comment: There is now a public beta site called "Music Fans" for song-related questions; see my revised answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is now a [Music Fans beta site](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/). Unfortunately, according to [its Area 51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans), it's not actually gaining all that much traction; it's averaging 2.4 questions per day and has 74 "avid users" (users with 200+ rep). Given the new policies about beta sites, though, it seems unlikely to be shut down any time soon.

As a point of trivia, there was an identical previous Area 51 proposal that did not even gain enough support to enter a public beta.

Comment: any reason why the previous one was deleted, and then again a new one came up?

Comment: @HappyCoder I think it just didn't generate enough momentum the first time around.

Comment: @HappyCoder Also, see Manishearth's answer; Music Fans is a bit of an odd fit for StackExchange. I like, it though (I'm one of the aforementioned "avid users," though I *just barely* have >200 rep, even counting my 100-point trusted user bonus).

Answer (score 5):

We have [Music SE](http://music.stackexchange.com), but that's about playing instruments and music theory, posing example questions, and voting (as well as sharing).

Note that SE sites are not for discussion, the associated chat rooms are. And open-ended questions like the third question are off-topic as well.

Comment: That may be why the Music Fans beta site (created since you answered this question) isn't doing fantastically.